# Related to C#.net printing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

There is some text on my tabpage and for printing that tabpage I am converting it into image and taking that image as print so this text is not clear after printing

Code on PrintdDocument is

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)

{
    Bitmap btmp = new Bitmap(this.tabPage1.Width, this.tabPage1.Height);
    tabPage1.DrawToBitmap(btmp, new Rectangle(0,0, this.tabPage1.Width, this.tabPage1.Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(btmp, 0,150);

}
```

Comment: What language is this question written in?

Comment: @lc. I'm not sure - it appears to be valid Java, but it could also be C#.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I was referring to the (pre-edit) question text, not the code.

Comment: @lc. Interestingly, the source code in this question appears to be (almost) syntactically valid in Java as well as C# (except for the capitalization of the word `object`.). :)

Comment: @AndersonGreen Java and C# certainly have their similarities

Comment: guys its in c# and dis is d problem what i m facing while developing my software...

Comment: I know Habib deserves some kind of badge for deciphering the original text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want better looking text, draw it on a high-resolution image. Better yet, output the text directly to e.graphics without going to the image first.

Comment: actually_not_only_it_contains_text_but_its_like_invoice_so_include_lines_rectangles

Comment: Those can also be drawn on e.graphics. That's the way it's normally done.